# Python: Multiple text processings from stdin

Tags: python

I want to write a python script which will be integrated in a shell pipeline. So it has to take some input text from std-input and print the result to the std-output. I have multiple text processings to chain. Some processings apply on each line, others, first need to detect some blocks before change.

I made a loop for each text processing but my problem is that I don't see how to chain them to have the next loop taking as input the ouput of the previous.

Here under is my first draft.
As I'm used to write shell scripts, I have the feeling that I will have to works with tempfiles but not sure it's the way to go in Python.
And I assume that it would be nicer if I put each loop's processing in a function, too.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

""" Sample of pre-processing formating script """

import fileinput
import re
import sys

""" Read StdIn """
lines_in = fileinput.input()
lines_out = ""

preform_txt_regex = re.compile(r"^  ")
code_block = ""

"""
Walk through the input and replace the 'preformatted text' (starting with 2 spaces) 
into 'Fixed width text' (<code>…</code>).
"""
for line in lines_in:
  if line.startswith("  "):
    code_block = code_block + preform_txt_regex.sub('', line)
  else:
    if code_block != "":
        lines_out = lines_out + "<syntaxhighlight lang='shell'>\n{}</syntaxhighlight>\n".format(code_block)
        code_block = ""
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    lines_out = lines_out + line

# Reset lines_in and lines_out
lines_in = lines_out.split("\n")
lines_out = ""

"""
Remove the all 'Category' tags
"""
for line in lines_in:
  lines_out = lines_out + re.sub(r'\[\[Cat[ée]gor.*:[^\]]*]]', r'', line)

"""
Few other string substitution
"""
for line in lines_in:
  [...]

""" Print the processed texts """
sys.stdout.write(lines_out)
```

Comment: to have the next loop taking as input the ouput of the previous. !!!, why don't you just keep the result in temporary variable , and use it after that, without print to the output, and then read it again ?

Comment: Your basic idea here looks right. - as @ibra says, you probably don't want to output anything until the very end. - next, you should think about what you want to do with each line after you process it each time through.  You could create a list with `buffer = []`and go through the list in a way that you can put the result of processing each line back into the same `buffer` object.

Comment: Indeed playing with a list of lines as buffer seems the way to go. Thanks @ibra and @Steve!

Answer (score 0):

Propositions from @Steve and @ibra were to use a list of lines as variable buffer. And indeed, I made something working like that.

So here is my code reviewed. I moved my processing loops in functions which take `lines_buffer` as parameter:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

""" Sample of pre-processing formating script """

import fileinput
import re
import sys

"""
Walk through the input and replace the 'preformatted text' (starting with 2 spaces) 
into 'Fixed width text' (<code>…</code>).
"""
def render_code_block(lines):
  preform_txt_regex = re.compile(r"^  ")
  code_block = []
  output = []
  for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("  "):
      code_block.append(preform_txt_regex.sub('', line))
    else:
      if code_block != []:
        output.append("<syntaxhighlight lang='shell'>\n{}</syntaxhighlight>\n".format(code_block))
        code_block = []
      output.append(line)
  return output

"""
Remove the all 'Category' tags
"""
def remove_category_tags(lines):
  output = []
  for line in lines:
    output.append(re.sub(r'\[\[Cat[ée]gor.*:[^\]]*]]', r'', line))
  return output

""" Main """
lines_buffer = []
lines_buffer = fileinput.input()
lines_buffer = render_code_block(lines_buffer)
lines_buffer = remove_category_tags(lines_buffer)
for line in lines_buffer:
  sys.stdout.write(line)
```

And of course, I had to replace the string initialization (`= ""`) by list initialization (`= []`) and `append` in place of concatenate (`+`).